# :nth-child() selector with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a front-end beginner and I have a question.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
            <li class="title">Who are you?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>First Name:</label><br />
                <input id="first_name" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Middle Name:</label><br />
                <input id="middle_name" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Last Name:</label><br />
                <input id="last_name" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Email:</label><br />
                <input id="emai" class="req" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
            <li class="title">Where are you?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>City:</label><br />
                <input id="city" type="text" /><br />
                <label>State:</label><br />
                <input id="state" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Country:</label><br />
                <input id="country" class="req" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
            <li class="title">What Do You Do?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>Occupation:</label><br />
                <input id="occupation" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Company:</label><br />
                <input id="company" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Company Location:</label><br />
                <input id="location" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("li.fields").filter(':nth-child(even)').addClass('hide');
});
```

I don't understand :nth-child logic! It seems like it ignores fields class. When I'm using :nth-child(odd) it doesn't hide any tabs. And with odd everything is open.
If you know the answer and you could share it would mean the world for me.
Thank you!

Comment: Because that is not how nth-child selector works when combined with a class. Your selector will select for any list item element that has the class `field` AND is an even child. It doesn’t select for every other `li.field` element. This is a very common misconception with how nth-child selectors work.

Comment: would be much easier to use `div`'s instead with a class on each section, if the aim is to do form steps or a collapse